# I'm trying to create a login authentication page but it returns me nothing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm trying to build a login system but when I put the username and password on Postman it returns me nothing. When I try to login with the correct user it returns me nothing aswell and it does nothing. I'm building this with the passportJS module and bcrypt to encrypt the password.

passport authentication:

```
const Users = require('../models/users.model.js')
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {
      Users.findOne({username: username}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if(result === true) {
            return done(null, user)
          } else {
            return done(null, false)
          }
        })
      })
    })
  )

  passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user.id)
  })

  passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    Users.findOne({_id: id}, (err, user) => {
      cb(err, user)
    })
  })
}
```

route for login configuration:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Users = require('../models/users.model.js')
const passport = require("passport")

require('../authentication/passportConfig.js')(passport)


router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  Users.find()
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error:' + err))
})

router.route('/login').post((req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local" , (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) res.send("No user exists")
    else {
      req.logIn(user, err => {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.send("Succesfully Authenticated")
        console.log(req.user)
      })
    }
  })
})
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const PORT = 4000;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const usersRoute = require("./routes/users.js");
const passport = require("passport")
const passportLocal = require("passport-local").Strategy
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")
const expressSession = require("express-session")


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
require('./authentication/passportConfig.js')(passport)

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://user:xxxxx@cluster0.bcveo.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

app.use('/users', usersRoute)

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", function() {
  console.log("Connection with MongoDB was successful");
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});
```

React where the action should be performed:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './login.css'
import axios from 'axios'

const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  const users = {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }

  axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/login', users)
  .then(res => console.log(res.data))
}
```

Comment: check this line ` bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {`  in this, if your password is "123", the user.password would be the encrypted one from DB. Hence check the user.password with the encrypted password

Comment: yes i know wht it does. IS anything incorrect in it?

Comment: try this  var {md5} = require('md5'); and use the following  bcrypt.compare(md5(password), user.password, (err, result) => {

Comment: @SelvaMary still not working

Answer (score 0):

Your post route is not calling the passport local strategy function [Passport Custom Callback](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/).

```js
router.route('/login').post((req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local" , (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) res.send("No user exists")
    else {
      req.logIn(user, err => {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.send("Succesfully Authenticated")
        console.log(req.user)
      })
    }
  })
})
```

change to

```js
router.route('/login').post((req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local" , (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) res.send("No user exists")
    else {
      req.logIn(user, err => {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.send("Succesfully Authenticated")
        console.log(req.user)
      })
    }
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

Comment: Why do you use router.route('/login'). Try the one i have updated

Comment: @SelvaMary which one you mean?

Comment: i changed the answer just compare the first line

Comment: Look into this [link][1] code provides basic configuration on passport and other strategies. You may need to change the setting according to your need


  [1]: https://github.com/BrentAureli/Youtube-Tutorials/tree/master/NodeJS%20Tutorials/Tutorial%20%2017%20-%20Issue%20And%20Expire%20Tokens